# Query Optimization Java - Using Query inside a nested Loop

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have come through following situation

```
 for(int i =1;i<=8028;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=1300;j++)
        {
          xyz = executeQuery("Select where abc = i and bcd = j")

        }   
    }
```

In above example, I guess the query executes 8028*1300 time which takes lots of time and resource.

Is there any way I could optimize this both for time and performance ?

Please excuse me for above code, its just a pseudoCode. Also let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: You could probably query the database a lot less (once? :p) and loop over the resultset somehow. Something like: `abc in range 1-8028, bcd in range 1-1300`.

Comment: if you are using statement then i would suggest you to use preparedstatement.This will take less time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
       xyz = executeQuery(" Select abc, bcd  from myTable"
+" where abc between 1 and 8028"
    +" and bcd between 1 and 1300")
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like "SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY abc, bcd WHERE abc in range 1-8028 AND bcd in range 1-1300" and then iterate over the result.

More information on the actual database structure are required to provide better answer

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Select * from your_Table where (abc between 1 and 8028) and (bcd between 1 and 1300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ...... where (abc between 1 and 8028) and (bcd between 1 and 1300)
```